# How do I convert an image into a buffer so that I can send it over using socket programming? C++

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

1. How do I convert an image into a buffer so that I can send it over using socket programming? I'm using C++ socket programming. I am also using QT for my Gui.
2. Also, after sending it over through the socket, how do I put that image back together so it can become a file again?

If someone could put up some sample code that would be great :)

I was looking around and found something about rfile but still not going through my head.

tyty

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815156/tips-examples-on-sending-an-image-file-jpeg-png-over-socket-programming

Comment: Yes, I think there's a reluctance to answer this question because it will probably result in a cascade of follow-up questions and no answer will be enough to meet the OP's needs. There's also a spooky simlarity between this question and the one Jonathan linked to. Something's not *as it seems*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to send an image as a file,
here is pseudocode to send it through a TCP connection.

Client A

```
Set up a connection  
Open a file in binary mode  
Loop:  
   read/load N bytes in a buffer  
   send(buffer)  
Close file  
Close connection
```

Client B

```
Listen and accept a connection  
Create a new file in binary mode  
Loop:  
   n = read(buffer)   
   write n bytes in the file
Close file  
Close connection
```

Comment: Just remember endianess issues.

Comment: @gnud, yes we have to take care of endianess when we fill the structures with data. In the case of transmitting a raw sequence of bytes, we can omit that step.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Qt, use a QImageWriter and a QImageReader and let them deal directly with the socket, thus avoiding the need for a temporary file.

Answer (score -1):

I figured this out as well and wrote down what I did. You can find the description here: http://hanckmann.net/?q=node/44. It is fine to download and use the examples there!